# Unreproducible webcore crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, crash

I've got an iPad app that's in the App Store for around three months now and I've been receiving some weird crash reports that I can't figure out. These are not that frequent, got around 15-20 instances since the launch but still frequent enough to actually bug me. The crashes are slightly different (see stack traces below) but since they are related to `WebCore` I'm guessing they have to do with the usage of the `UIWebView` in the app and might have a common cause, though I'm not 100% positive. The deployment target of the app is iOS 6.0 but crashes appear on iPad 2, iPad 3 and iPad Mini, exclusively on iOS 7.

There is only one place in the app where I'm using a webview, for displaying news article web pages from various sources. I have one view controller for this that has a `UIWebView` as its view. There is one instance of this view controller that lives throughout the app, each time a new article is selected the existing webview reloads with the url of the newly selected article.

One of the proposed solutions based on the discussion around WebCore issues suggested setting the webviews `delegate` property to `nil` in the controller's `dealloc` method. Unfortunately I don't think it's applicable in my case because the view controller does not get deallocated during the lifecycle of the app.
Another issue might be incorrect webpages that have bad image references in the CSS (loadPendingImages crash). I couldn't find such a page yet though.
Also, I double-checked and made sure to do webview-related operations on the main thread.

The crashes are

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
```

with the following stack traces (full ones [here](http://cl.ly/text/0D3e120B151K))

```
0 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::applyMatchedProperties(WebCore::StyleResolver::MatchResult const&, WebCore::Element const*) + 815
1 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::applyMatchedProperties(WebCore::StyleResolver::MatchResult const&, WebCore::Element const*) + 788
2 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::styleForElement(WebCore::Element*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::StyleSharingBehavior, WebCore::RuleMatchingBehavior, WebCore::RenderRegion*) + 948
3 WebCore WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 96
4 WebCore WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 142
5 WebCore WebCore::ComputedStyleExtractor::propertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID, WebCore::EUpdateLayout) const + 458
```

and

```
0 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::loadPendingImages() + 1153
1 WebCore WebCore::ResourceRequestBase::~ResourceRequestBase() + 104
2 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::applyMatchedProperties(WebCore::StyleResolver::MatchResult const&, WebCore::Element const*) + 782
3 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::styleForElement(WebCore::Element*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::StyleSharingBehavior, WebCore::RuleMatchingBehavior, WebCore::RenderRegion*) + 948
4 WebCore WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 96
5 WebCore WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 142
```

and

```
0 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::adjustRenderStyle(WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::Element*) + 19
1 WebCore WebCore::StyleResolver::styleForElement(WebCore::Element*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::StyleSharingBehavior, WebCore::RuleMatchingBehavior, WebCore::RenderRegion*) + 964
2 WebCore WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 96
3 WebCore WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 142
4 WebCore WebCore::ComputedStyleExtractor::propertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID, WebCore::EUpdateLayout) const + 458
5 WebCore WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID) const + 42
```

and

```
0 WebCore WebCore::TimerBase::heapDeleteMin() + 37
1 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 94
2 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 94
3 WebCore WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 24
4 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
5 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 782
```

Has anyone experienced similar crashes? If so:
1. Are there ways to replicate them?
2. How can one debug these without replicating them?
3. What fixes solved the issues?

Thanks!

Comment: iOS 7 has several major issues with graphics rendering. The issue you are attempting to track down is likely and OS-level, (or SDK-level) issue. To venture a blind guess, there is some CSS transforms or animations that are causing the crash. Your only hope of isolating the cause is to find the page that causes it, and even then you probably won't be able to do anything about it.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I didn't get to replicate it myself yet and since I'm loading news articles from various (30+) news sources I have a feeling I won't be able to do it anytime soon. In case nobody else will have a better idea on what might be going on here, we'll have to wait for iOS 7.1 and see if they address any of these issues.

Comment: I've been replicating this error in cordova ios7 with using window.requestAnimationFrame in a recursion loop to step animate sprite emoticons.  Seems that it can happens when the app awakes from a long sleep and tries to animate again.

Comment: 7.1 does not fix these issues, unfortunately. Not in beta2, at least.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue in an app I worked on, it weirdly only occurred on older devices running iOS 7. I suspect this has something to do with them not being able to keep up.

What I had was a `UITableView` where one of the rows would open a `UIViewController` that had a `UIWebView` on it for custom adverts. What I found is that on the older devices objects and memory where being free'd up far more regularly than I'd seen in other platforms. I could mimic the crash very easily on an iPhone 4 by going in / out of the screen 2 or 3 times. Where as an iPhone 5 I spent 15 minutes doing the same and couldn't fault it.

I know you may feel like your controller is not being dealloc'd but it really sounds as though it is or some reference is being dropped, I have also seen my delegate references disappear a few times in this app also.

My advice and what worked for me is to stop the execution of the webview and set everything to `nil` when you can.

In one instance on my app I chose to do it on the `viewWillDisappear` callback, because in my circumstance it was gone from the user and recreated later, so I blanked everything like so:

```
[webView stopLoading];

self.webView.delegate = nil;
self.webView = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Simon. I'll have to try this. Unfortunately, since I can't replicate the issue I won't be able to know whether this worked or not, at least until I release an update to my app.

Comment: @BotondSzékely hopefully it helps you out, one quick way would be to do what I did and send out a message to all of your friends and ask to borrow an older device for a few days. I find iPhone 4's handle iOS 7 very poorly

Comment: A note of caution to anyone who just takes that code above as-is. You may introduce bugs if you have screens the user can get to from the screen that has the webview. For example, imagine you have a navigation bar button that pushes another screen on the navigation controller. It will call `viewWillDisappear` and clear out `self.webView.delegate` and `self.webView`. Then when you come back to the webview screen you'll still see the webview, but any code that references `self.webView` will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Javascript-to-Objective-C code and if you are executing/calling javascript code make sure that script does not invoke new calls to Objective-C.

This is proper usage:

```
Javascript >> Objective-C

Objective-C >> Javascript
```

This is reason for crash:

`Objective-C >> Javascript >> Objective-C` (here is possible crash depending on some race conditions)

Solution is specific for your project code. But easiest would be to wrap all Javascript in `setTimeout()` to schedule execution in Javascript thread. Here is simple example, your Objective-C code needs to execute this script:

```
storeUserPhoneNumber("011 123 4567");
```

Crash will happen if `storeUserPhoneNumber` function calls back to Objective-C code (directly or indirectly) in its body. To fix this just wrap code in setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    storeUserPhoneNumber("011 123 4567");
}, 0);
```

What this accomplishes is to parse Javascript code from string and place it in function that is scheduled to be executed later on next event-loop tick releasing control back to Objective-C after parsing JS code.

Remember you need this fix on all `Objective-C >> Javascript` calls ;)

Comment: If you are right, your answer is very interesting. Do you have any documentation/references/sample projects backing up your claims ? Why would "Objective-C >> Javascript >> Objective-C" cause a crash ? And what about javascript executed from Objective-C not executed on the javascript thread ? It seems weird that this wouldn't be documented.

Comment: @deadbeef It is easily reproducible with simple test project if you want to spend some time to confirm for your self. I consider this to be a bug in IOS implementation and not a feature to be documented.