# iOS 8 WebCore:WebVideoFullscreenModelMediaElement:updateForEventName

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, youtube, ios8

I am just play the youtube video on WebView.

Please find the attached screen shot.
[image]
My app have crash due to **WebCore::WebVideoFullscreenModelMediaElement::updateForEventName** and for crash report, I have used Crashlytics but Whenever I have tested in development that time its not crashed.

I am also follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859414/unreproducible-webcore-crashes)
So please give me the suggestion or any idea why this occur issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting same issue in my appstore build. You got any success ?

Comment: @Tariq No buddy but you can handle with try catch exception in webView allocation and also if push to another view controller, you can webView delegate set to nil and and set to webView nil. Hope its working for you.